When adding ImageView programmatically, the view does not obey layout constraint
I am developing an Android app page. This page will load images from a URL. However, the loaded images do not obey the layout constraint. The result has some unexpected blank space. Why, and how to solve this?
Here is my code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".for_dynamic_add_img_and_desc">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

package com.example.emptyactivityjava;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class for_dynamic_add_img_and_desc extends AppCompatActivity {

    LinearLayout LinearLayout_content;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_for_dynamic_add_img_and_desc);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });

        LinearLayout_content = findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout_content);

        String[] imgs_url = {
                "https://amateurphotographer.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2023/04/Paulina-Stopka-vertical-landscapes-Tryfan-Eryri-National-Park-Tatra-Mountains.jpg",
                "https://images.pexels.com/photos/247599/pexels-photo-247599.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",
                "https://samuelearp.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/10/IMG_1512-1536x1273.jpeg",
        };

        String[] descs = {
                "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb",
                "cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc"
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(for_dynamic_add_img_and_desc.this).inflate(R.layout.item_template, null);
            Picasso.get().load(imgs_url[i]).into((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img));
            ((TextView) (view.findViewById(R.id.desc))).setText(descs[i]);
            LinearLayout_content.addView(view);
        }
    }
}

item_template.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/img" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

The result has some unexpected blank space. How do I solve this?


Why don't you try using RecyclerView instead of ScrollView?

This is not the correct way to implement a list like this, instead of using a ScrollView you must use RecyclerView check here
